# Using different content-encoding for Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to be able to support Brotli and Gzip encoding for static assets hosted with Google Cloud Storage. To do this I want to encode files before they are uploaded as `<filename>`, `<filename>.gz` and `<filename>.br`. The issue is, I can't find a way to redirect a request with `Accept-Encoding` to the correct file.

I have looked into using:

- Cloud Functions to somehow redirect incoming requests (similar to AWS Cloudfront Lambda), but it does not seem to be supported
- Load Balancer to redirect requests to different buckets, but as far as I could see it can only redirect based on hostname/path to different buckets
- Cloud CDN, but it does not seem to have any functionality that helps with this

#### Requests/Response examples

Assume bucket `example-bucket` contains the following files:

```
library.js
library.js.gz
library.js.br
```

Example 1

```
GET http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/library.js

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

```
Content-Encoding: br

<Contents of http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/library.js.br>
```

Example 2

```
GET http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/library.js

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

```
Content-Encoding: gzip

<Contents of http://storage.googleapis.com/example-bucket/library.js.gz>
```

---

Is there a way to accomplish the above in a manner that is simple, performant and cost effective? I realize it's possible to just host my own server via App Engine, and let that take care of routing requests to the bucket, but is this the only way?

Comment: Cloud Storage won't do this for you.  You will have to write your own code on your own endpoint to make these sorts of decisions.  If you're having a trouble with a specific solution, that would be something else to ask a question about.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was asking since this is possible to do on AWS via the [Lambda@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html). Was hoping to avoid hosting an application for this, as they can easily become the bottleneck (compared to CDN and static hosted files).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda@edge is a way to do it but the simple way is to Whitelist the Accept-encoding header on CloudFront so CloudFront can pass it to Origin and you can have the Configuration on Origin to serve file based on the Accept-encoding header.

If you planning to use Lambda@edge, I would suggest using the Origin request function.
1. Whitelist the Accept-encoding header
2.Origin request function to read the header value and change the request URI path.